# Converting subset to TIFF in MODIS

Tags: gdal, r

I am very new in this field. I have many MODIS MYD05_L2 files. I want to batch convert them to TIFF format. I tried with HEG but as far as I understand, it cannot be done in bulk there. The other day, I ran the following code on the command line for testing purposes and it gave 24 outputs. I only need Near infrared (NIR) and infrared (IR) observations. Also, the tape numbers of all files are 1. So I can't do it with -b or mask. How can I get only this subset? As far as I researched, it could be done with subset, but as I said, I couldn't understand it because I was very new. How can I do this?

The code I tried:

```
for %A in ("c:\Test\Modis_\*.hdf") do gdal_translate -of GTiff -sds "%A" "%A.tiff"
```

Answer (score 1):

The files of MYD05_L2 have three bands:

```r
[1] "Cloud_Mask_QA"                  "Water_Vapor_Near_Infrared"     
[3] "Water_Vapor_Correction_Factors"
```

for reading and writing each file, first make a vector with filenames, then read and write as tif; although  you should consider gdal_translate should be faster

```r
hdfs = list.files(pattern = ".hdf", full.names = TRUE) 
lapply(hdfs[1:10], #try for a subset from [1:10], when it works remove
    function(x) {
    rast(x)$Water_Vapor_Near_Infrared |> writeRaster(gsub(".hdf", "_wvni.tif", x))
    rast(x)$Water_Vapor_Correction_Factors |> writeRaster(gsub(".hdf", "_wvcf.tif", x)
}
)
```

Comment: Actually, MYD05_L2 consists of 11 sub-datasets  - c.f. [docs](https://atmosphere-imager.gsfc.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/ModAtmo/MYD05_L2.C6.CDL.fs) or output of `terra::describe()`. Guess @ali is interested in getting the subsets `"Water_Vapor_Near_Infrared"` and `"Water_Vapor_Infrared"`. The latter, among others, does not seem to be recognized by `terra::rast()`. Maybe this is due to differences in spatial resolution between layers: 4 layers have 2030x1354 cells, the 7 remaining layers 406x270 cells. `terra` seems to recognize 6 out of these using `sds()`.

Comment: Moreover: "The file contains 13 gridded parameters. Each of these gridded MYD05 parameters is stored as a Scientific Data Set (SDS) within the HDF-EOS file. The Water Vapor and Quality Assurance SDS's are stored at 1 kilometer (near-infrared) and 5 kilometer (for infrared) pixel resolution." ([source](https://modaps.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/services/about/products/c6/MYD05_L2.html)) Last update: 02/2015. Maybe this information is outdated. GDAL only seems to recognize 11 sub-datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the development version of terra, you can now - thanks to @rhijmans! - execute something like:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.33

# list files
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.hdf$", full.names = TRUE)
files
#> [1] "MYD05_L2.A2012308.0100.061.2018043055834.hdf"
#> [2] "MYD05_L2.A2012308.0105.061.2018043060040.hdf"
#> [3] "MYD05_L2.A2012308.0110.061.2018043055832.hdf"

# due to missing georeference information, `rast()` and `sds()` do not work as intended with MYD05_L2
s <- sprc(files[1])
s
#> class       : SpatRasterCollection 
#> length      : 11 
#> nrow        : 406, 406, 406, 406, 406, 2030, 2030, 2030, 406, 1354, 270 
#> ncol        : 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 1354, 1354, 1354, 270,    1,   5 
#> nlyr        :   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,    1,    1,    1,   1, 2030, 406 
#> names       : Scan_Start_Time, Solar_Zenith, Solar_Azimuth, Sensor_Zenith, Sensor_Azimuth, Cloud_Mask_QA, ...

# inspect layer names
n <- names(s)
n
#>  [1] "Scan_Start_Time"                 "Solar_Zenith"                   
#>  [3] "Solar_Azimuth"                   "Sensor_Zenith"                  
#>  [5] "Sensor_Azimuth"                  "Cloud_Mask_QA"                  
#>  [7] "Water_Vapor_Near_Infrared"       "Water_Vapor_Correction_Factors" 
#>  [9] "Water_Vapor_Infrared"            "Quality_Assurance_Near_Infrared"
#> [11] "Quality_Assurance_Infrared"

# determine relevant index
which(n %in% c("Water_Vapor_Infrared", "Water_Vapor_Near_Infrared"))
#> [1] 7 9

# iterate over files, subset, and save as TIFF
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  
  s <- sprc(files[i])
  
  r1 <- s[7] 
  writeRaster(r1, gsub(".hdf", "_NIR.tif", files[i]))
  
  r2 <- s[9] 
  writeRaster(r2, gsub(".hdf", "_IR.tif", files[i]))
}

# check results
list.files(pattern = "\\.tif$")
#> [1] "MYD05_L2.A2012308.0100.061.2018043055834_IR.tif" 
#> [2] "MYD05_L2.A2012308.0100.061.2018043055834_NIR.tif"
#> [3] "MYD05_L2.A2012308.0105.061.2018043060040_IR.tif" 
#> [4] "MYD05_L2.A2012308.0105.061.2018043060040_NIR.tif"
#> [5] "MYD05_L2.A2012308.0110.061.2018043055832_IR.tif" 
#> [6] "MYD05_L2.A2012308.0110.061.2018043055832_NIR.tif"
```

Since the MYD05_L2 hdf files do not have all relevant spatial information hardcoded in the right place, you might want to manually set extent and/or crs information using e.g. `ext(r1) <- ...` and `crs(r1) <- ...` prior to `writeRaster()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try it at the first opportunity. Can I also use this code for Aqua files?

Comment: Since MODIS is used with Aqua and Terra, I would not expect structural differences between MYD05_L2 and MOD05_L2.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. I'll write as soon as I try.

Comment: @ali: Where does execution fail exactly and would you please provide an error message? Note: I just checked and it seems like all IR layers seem to be doing fine, more or less, but the NIR layers are having issues - in every software I tried. R/terra, QGIS, Panoply. IR seems to be recognized properly, but not NIR. Maybe there are some deviations in data production process not leading to results according to HDF standards? Are you able to access NIR properly with some other environment?

Comment: I solved the problem I just mentioned. But now when I want to use sprc function I get the following error. I guess it's getting the files as chr.
`s <- sprc(files[1])`
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) :
   unable to find an inherited method for function 'sprc' for signature '"character"'

Comment: You need to use the development version of terra for this (c.f. [rspatial/terra#855](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/855)), not the CRAN one. To install, type `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you. I tried it in MOD05 files and the codes are working :) Only NIR files do not create images. I tried it with randomly downloaded files from 2019, so that may be why. I looked at the NIR images with HEG, usually there is no image. Only one of them had a different image. It can't be seen because it's too black, but it's clearer than the code output.